# Google Closure Stylesheets parse error with @media only screen

Tags: css, google-closure-stylesheet

I'm using closure-stylesheets-20111230.jar to combine and minify all my CSS. However it's throwing parsing error with **@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px)** on something that looks fine to me.

**Google closure-stylesheets.jar to parse css:**

> java -jar closure-stylesheets.jar  ..\data\css\mycss.css --output-file
>   ..\data\css\myresult.css

**CSS code:**

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
.switchMobile{ padding: 33px 0 0 0; height: 90px; }
.switchMobile a { font-size: 300%; }   
#closeMobileLink{ margin: -60px 20px; }   
}
```

Any thoughts? I have just use their closure-stylesheets.jar file but was wondering if anyone had a proper solution. Thanks!

Comment: 20111230 means December 30, 2011. Apparently no one has pushed a new version to the Downloads section in quite a while! However, code changes have been pushed to the source repo since then (https://code.google.com/p/closure-stylesheets/source/list) so you might try building from source instead.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is really very old. The question does not include any parsing error message. On 'new' closure-stylesheets I can't compile your stylesheet because of the space between `min-device-width` and the colon; I also get an error message pointing this out.

```
Compiler parsing error: Parse error in stylesheet.gss at line 2 column 22:
and (min-device-width : 320px)
```

If I remove the space, the stylesheet compiles without issues.